# How to connect Celery with redis?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have taken a free trial for Redis and it gave me an endpoint with a password. I haven't done anything with Redis or celery before so I really don't have any idea how it works. From the Docs of Celery everyone connects to the local host but how can I connect to this endpoint?

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
```

What should I replace this with? Where should I give the password?

My endpoint looks something like this: `redis-18394.c252.######.cloud.redislabs.com:18394`, Should I add the password at the end of this after a `/` ?

Answer (score 4):

According to celery's documentation, the format is

```
redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number
```

By default, redis has 16 databases so you can use any number from 0-15 for db_number.  Use a different db number for broker and result backend.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html#configuration

Comment: I can confirm, this format worked. I set the broker URL to the redis endpoint with password and set db_number to 0.

Comment: where to put username in this format? Before password and the preceding colon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [channel_redis](https://github.com/django/channels_redis) for this

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": ["password@your_ip"],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you just show me the full code? How does this channel be given to celery?

Comment: I have added the repo link just above the code. It has a good readme that you can refer to!